# How to decompile with Hex Rays via a Python API?

Tags: ida, idapython, python, hexrays, idapro-sdk

If i have a large set of files and I'd like to run Hex-rays over them to produce output as C - can I do so in python?

- I see there is IDA Python
- And I see Hex-rays has a C++ SDK

Is there a python Hex-rays API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The newer versions of IDA has official bindings for the Hex-Rays decompiler.
Originally, the Python bindings were written by [EiNSTeiN](https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/hexrays-python) around the Hex-Rays Decompiler SDK API. Later it has been merged into IDAPython.

You can find the documentation under "*ida_hexrays*" in the [IDAPython docs](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/).
Examples can be found in IDAPython [repository](https://github.com/idapython/src/tree/master/examples). Check the scripts which starting with "*vds*".

You can check [IDA Batch Decompile](https://github.com/tintinweb/ida-batch_decompile) plugin which aims, as stated by the author, to batch decompile files in a folder:

> *IDA Batch Decompile* is a plugin for Hex-Ray's IDA Pro that adds the
>   ability to batch decompile multiple files and their imports with
>   additional annotations (xref, stack var size) to the pseudocode .c
>   file

Notice that this is a work-in-progress project so you might encounter some bugs.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on IDA version you're using.
Version 7.0 (and AFAIR version 6.9) has [ida_hexrays](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_hexrays-module.html) python module which has functions `decompile` and `decompile_many`. 
If I remember it correctly the older IDA versions had these functions in `idaapi` module and these functions already had been introduced in IDA 6.6.

Answer (score 2):

Well,there exist some examples at the idapython's github, see the idapyhton/examples/vds1.py,you can get a demo.

```
import idaapi
f=idaapi.get_func(ea)
cfunc=idaapi.decompile(f)
```

I have tried this on ida pro 6.8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. In the end I used retdec due to some licensing restrictions. I can't share the exact code used, but this might be useful for others looking at this too:

Docker-IDA -  https://github.com/intezer/docker-ida - Can be changed to work on HexRays fairly easily

Then commands such as the following may be useful:

['/ida/idat','-Ohexrays:outfile:ALL','-A',folder + 'input.bin'])

['mono','/dnSpy/dnSpy.Console.exe',filename,'-o', outdir]

['/retdec/bin/decompile.sh','-l','py',filename]